# Oracle sql hash with salt

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using to STANDARD_HASH to hash the employee IDs from a table in Oracle 12g.

```
SELECT employee_id, standard_HASH(employee_id,'SHA256')
FROM employees
```

How do i use a unique salt for each hash.

Comment: Can't you prepend the salt of your choosing to the (char representation of) `employee_id`?

Comment: that is a very good idea... i didnt think of it..